# Name of book about a man who was genetically modified during prehistoric times by aliens

Tags: story-identification

I read a book about a man who was geneticall modified during prehistoric times by aliens, and lived forever. I keep thinking it was Ben Bova or Greg Bear story but I cannot think of it. I read it as a kid and now I cannot remember name or author. It seemed to follow his life through out history into modern times. I have googled this to no end. Anyone recall this book?

Comment: Can you give me the year you think it was published or at least when you think you read it, it would help. I have been lucky in finding hidden gems, maybe I can find it for you and have friends in the library that I can reach out to.

Comment: Was the hero Neanderthal or Cro-Magnon? What was the aliens' motivation? After they modify this guy in prehistoric times do they disappear from the story, or do they keep in touch?

Comment: My memory is so vague during this period. I am going to read Orion and see if it rings an bells. Thanks all for the comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you described fits a book called "**In the Face of My Enemy**" by Joseph H. Delaney from the early 1980s.

> In it a prehistoric man, Kah-Sih-Omah, is modified by aliens which allows him to totally control his genetic makeup and organic structure.  He never ages, he can regenerate his limbs and resist all disease.  He can alter his structure to incorporate capabilities from other species (e.g. night vision from felines, improved sight from avians, etc).

The plot line continues into modern day and then into the future. The [book cover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671559931) and reader description can be viewed on Amazon.

Comment: I know this late in coming, but this ended up being the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds kind of like Apocalypse from the X-Men.

Answer (score 10):

Are you thinking of the [*Orion* series](http://benbova.com/nonfictionorionarticles/) by Ben Bova?

> Orion is a superpowered hero but not a superhero.
>   No cape, no tights, no flying, fast but not a runner, smart but not a genius, the sort of hero most of us would be
>   if we could live again and again and had just a decent edge on the rest of the world.
>   Pursuing his love, the ‘god’ Anya across the centuries he strives to break from from his creator and set the world aright!

Comment: The timeline throughout history seems roughly right but it's reversed, and I don't recall any genetic modifications, but it's the series which sprang to mind for me too.

Comment: @moopet - Orion was designed by the Creators, if I recall.

Comment: False memory as we age really sucks, and I could be filling in what little detail there is. Going to check out the Orion series and see if it is indeed the one. Thanks all.