# An immortal who travels space trying to find the aliens who made him immortal

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find out about a series I read when I was younger. It was about either a cave man or ancient native American who was turned immortal by aliens. He travels across space trying to find the aliens that "fixed him".

I seem to remember that he was a shaman ready to die when the aliens accidently hurt him while landing their ship and they decided to fix him.
I keep thinking the characters name is casey, or KC for some reason.

I also remember in the short story that he can regenerate mass to replace damaged or missing body parts by eating.

Comment: You're not thinking about Poul Anderson's _[The Boat of a Million Years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boat_of_a_Million_Years)_?

Comment: this sounds rad!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Neolithic shaman becomes immortal, after being healed by aliens](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103007/neolithic-shaman-becomes-immortal-after-being-healed-by-aliens)

Comment: @MrLister doesn't really match except for having immortal humans

Comment: @AakashM It does feature one caveman and one native American, and in the end they travel across space looking for aliens...

Comment: @RogueJedi The other way around then. This one is a better developed question; as soon as Azzan returns and accepts this, the other one can be closed.

Answer (score 7):

Possibly [*In the Face of My Enemy*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6655) by Joseph Delaney? Per the summary provided by beichst (whom you can thank for the find) in response to [another more recent question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103007/neolithic-shaman-becomes-immortal-after-being-healed-by-aliens):

> Eighteen thousand years ago a priest ascended a high place, there to
> hold converse with his gods. That night the gods chose to bless him
> with their physical reality. Alas, mortal flesh cannot bear the
> presence of godhead, and so he died. And was reborn. But ever after he
> was not as other men. He could change his form at will, his wounds
> healed instantly. . . and he did not age. As millennia passed he grew
> very wise, and came at last to understand. His destiny lay not among
> men, but among the stars.

Comment: Turns out this was the answer to a much earlier question, as well. See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40396/name-of-book-about-a-man-who-was-genetically-modified-during-prehistoric-times-b