# Neolithic shaman becomes immortal, after being healed by aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, immortality

The story is about a neolithic shaman who becomes injured by aliens, and when they heal them they make him immortal.

Comment: How long ago did you read it?

Comment: What happens next? Does he live forever? When is it set? What is his name? Is he the hero or the villain?

Comment: There's a similar but reversed version of this that I *think* was written by Turtledove where human members of an exploration and anthropology team find a planet where a queen is everything you could wish for in a ruler. She is dying and one of the humans sneaks out at night to give her a general spectrum cure. Couple thousand years later they return to find that she's still alive and still an amazing Queen. She realizes who and what they are and decides that next time, she'll go to meet them.

Comment: He pretty much lives forever, the story flashes back every now and then to different times in history.

Comment: @Broklynite - http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/Noninterference That was exactly the same story I thought of, too

Comment: It is not the Turtledove story, although that was a great one.

Comment: just refreshed my google search and now the top result is this thread  lol

Comment: The novel by Turtledove is called "Noninterference"  http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/Noninterference

Comment: The chain of events is started by an agent of the Federacy Survey Service secretly observing the humanoid inhabitants of Bilbeis IV, living in a Bronze Age culture. The agent is greatly impressed with the Queen of a local city state, who is a highly efficient administrator, very benevolent and beloved by her people, and also very progress-mined, actively promoting and rewarding technical innovation and new knowledge.

Comment: Discovering that the Queen is terminally ill with cancer, the Earth agent breaks the Survey Service's most fundamental rule, the Rule of Non-Interference. He pretends to be a healer from a distant part of the planet and administers a Federacy medicine. Though the locals are not quite the same as Earth humans, the Queen's life is saved. The agent's career is ended, and he is made an example of how not to behave. However, he feels that it was well worth the price, admitting to himself that he is in fact in love with the Queen, though she would never know of it.

Comment: 1500 years later, another Federacy ship visits the planet. Expecting to find the ancient Interference to have had no more than a local and brief effect, they are shocked to discover that the medicine did not just heal the Queen - it made her immortal. After 1500 years she is still very much around, worshiped as "The Goddess" and heading a world-wide benevolent and progressive theocracy.

Comment: Oops, downvoted by accident. Made a trivial edit (inserted a comma) so I could correct it to an upvote. Sorry about that.

Comment: ["The Gnarly Man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gnarly_Man) by L. Sprague de Camp is a Golden Age story about an immortal Neanderthal living more or less undercover who is "outed" by anthropologists, although there are no aliens involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is the novel In the Face of My Enemy by Joseph Delaney.  Below is a book review and cover:

[Amazon Book Review](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671559931)

[Plot Description](http://www.fictiondb.com/author/joseph-h-delaney~in-the-face-of-my-enemy~136379~b.htm)

> Eighteen thousand years ago a priest ascended a high place, there to hold converse with his gods. That night the gods chose to bless him with their physical reality. Alas, mortal flesh cannot bear the presence of godhead, and so he died. And was reborn. But ever after he was not as other men. He could change his form at will, his wounds healed instantly. . . and he did not age. As millennia passed he grew very wise, and came at last to understand. His destiny lay not among men, but among the stars.

Comment: I just read 'The Face of My Enemy' and it is a novella (or maybe a bit shorter).

Comment: Thank you,  In the face of my enemy is what i was looking for,  now i just have to find a copy  :)

Comment: @user1155120 It's both [a novella](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49396) and [a novel](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6655), and it's by Delaney, not Delany.

Comment: Glad I could help.  @user1155120, thank you for catching the typo.