# Looking for a novel about an immortal man probably written in the 1960s; follows his life through being an Inca king and a viking

Tags: story-identification, novel, immortality

A prehistoric man encounters an alien spaceship.  The aliens decide, for whatever reason, to make the man immortal.  The novel describes all the lives the man has had; Inca king, Viking, modern man.  He describes how he has to move from region to region to hide his secret.

Comment: Substitute "Jesus" for "Aliens" and "Roman Centurion" for "prehistoric man", and you basically have the *Casca* series by Barry Sadler.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151926/finding-a-book-with-a-man-from-the-future-being-reincarnated-on-earth-in-past-ti

Answer (score 17):

I believe this is [Ben Bova's series, *Orion*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/51197-orion), about an immortal cave man, following his defense of Humanity through the ages.  There are six books in the series.

> John O'Ryan is not a god...not exactly. He is an eternal warrior destined to combat the Dark Lord through all time for dominion of the Earth. Follow him, servant of a great race, as he battles his enemy down the halls of time, from the caves of our ancestors to the final confrontation under the hammer of nuclear annihilation.

Comment: +1 for reminding me to add this series to my Kindle list.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible that you are looking for *[In the Face of My Enemy](https://www.fictiondb.com/author/joseph-h-delaney%7Ein-the-face-of-my-enemy%7E136379%7Eb.htm)* by Joseph Delaney, published in 1985.

> Eighteen thousand years ago a priest ascended a high place, there to hold converse with his gods. That night the gods chose to bless him with their physical reality. Alas, mortal flesh cannot bear the presence of godhead, and so he died.
>
> And was reborn. But ever after he was not as other men. He could change his form at will, his wounds healed instantly. . . and he did not age.
>
> As millennia passed he grew very wise, and came at last to understand. His destiny lay not among men, but among the stars.

Comment: I personally think *Orion* is a better match, but if it is this one, it's also covered at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40396/name-of-book-about-a-man-who-was-genetically-modified-during-prehistoric-times-b and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103007/neolithic-shaman-becomes-immortal-after-being-healed-by-aliens

Comment: This was the one I first thought of when I saw the question. One thing that bothered me when I read my copy was that it seemed as if half of the hero's adventures were alluded to, but never detailed within the pages of the book. Stories that weren't collected in it, or that the author plotted out, but never got around to writing?

Answer (score 0):

The Casca Series by Barry Sadler might be what you are looking for. Fantastic reads, and collectible!

Comment: Could you also explain how this work fits the asker's description?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE I would suggest that you read through our [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information about the sorts of answers we are looking for.

Comment: Hi Nicole. For answers to story identification questions we normally include enough information from the book to allow the OP to decide if this really is the answer. This could be quotes from the book if you have a copy, or even just quotes from an online review that show why you think your suggested book is the answer. For example you could quote from the first book to show how Casca was cursed by Jesus and at the time of the book has ended up as a soldier in Vietnam. And as I recall Casca does get involved with both Vikings and Aztecs (rather than Incas) in book 2.